Query that uses "connect by" takes long to execute
I wrote an SQL query in Oracle SQL . This SQL query adds dates after 01.10.2024 to the credit_history table. I used `connect by` for this. But this query takes a long time to execute. As a result, not all the rows are returned and the system keeps spinning.
    select "REP_DATE","GRE","CR" 
      from CREDIT_HISTORY

     union all

    select distinct add_months(trunc(rep_date, 'mm'), level - 1), 
           gre, 
           cr  
      from CREDIT_HISTORY 
     where rep_date = to_date('15/04/2024', 'dd/mm/yyyy') 
connect by level <= months_between(trunc(sysdate, 'mm'), 
                                   to_date('15/04/2024', 'dd/mm/yyyy')) 
       and prior dbms_random.value is not null

     union all

    select distinct add_months(trunc(rep_date, 'mm'), level), 
           gre, 
           cr 
      from CREDIT_HISTORY 
     where rep_date = to_date('01/10/2024', 'dd/mm/yyyy') 
connect by level <= months_between(trunc(sysdate, 'mm'), 
                                   to_date('01/10/2024', 'dd/mm/yyyy'))  
       and prior dbms_random.value is not null; 

This is my SQL query code. I must use distinct` and  two connect by.
How can change query with same logic but small execution time?

Your CONNECT BY query does not correlate one row to the previous row so it will connect each row to all other rows in the hierarchy and generates exponentially increasing numbers of duplicate rows. To prevent the query detecting a loop you need to generate a unique value for each row, which is done by generating a GUID. You can then get rid of the duplicate rows using DISTINCT. This is incredibly inefficient as you generate huge numbers of rows and perform unique calculations to generate GUIDs for each and then get rid of most of the rows.
If you fix your query so that you are not generating duplicates and do not need to generate GUIDs then it will be much, much more efficient. You can do that by using a LATERAL join to a row generator.

You appear to want:

All the rows from the CREDIT_HISTORY table.
Plus the row(s) from the CREDIT_HISTORY table, where rep_date is either 2024-04-15 or 2024-10-01, duplicated for each month between then and today with rep_date set to the start of the month starting from the beginning of the 2024-04-01 for the date 2024-04-15 and from 2024-11-01 for 2024-10-01 (with a minimum of one row).

To do that, from Oracle 12, you can use:
SELECT m.rep_date,
       ch.gre,
       ch.cr
FROM   CREDIT_HISTORY ch
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT ch.rep_date
         FROM    DUAL
       UNION ALL
         SELECT ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(ch.rep_date, 'MM'), LEVEL - 1)
         FROM   DUAL
         START WITH ch.rep_date = DATE '2024-04-15'
         CONNECT BY level <= MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, ch.rep_date)
       UNION ALL
         SELECT ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(ch.rep_date, 'MM'), LEVEL)
         FROM   DUAL
         START WITH ch.rep_date = DATE '2024-10-01'
         CONNECT BY level <= MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, ch.rep_date)
       ) m

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE credit_history (rep_date, gre, cr) AS
SELECT DATE '2024-04-15', 1, 'C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2024-04-15', 2, 'D' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2024-10-01', 3, 'C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2024-10-01', 4, 'C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2024-06-09', 5, 'D' FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



REP_DATE
GRE
CR




2024-04-15 00:00:00
1
C


2024-04-01 00:00:00
1
C


2024-05-01 00:00:00
1
C


2024-06-01 00:00:00
1
C


2024-07-01 00:00:00
1
C


2024-08-01 00:00:00
1
C


2024-04-15 00:00:00
2
D


2024-04-01 00:00:00
2
D


2024-05-01 00:00:00
2
D


2024-06-01 00:00:00
2
D


2024-07-01 00:00:00
2
D


2024-08-01 00:00:00
2
D


2024-10-01 00:00:00
3
C


2024-11-01 00:00:00
3
C


2024-10-01 00:00:00
4
C


2024-11-01 00:00:00
4
C


2024-06-09 00:00:00
5
D



The same as your current query.
fiddle
